# How does python process a signal?

Tags: python, signals, extend

What is the workflow of processing a signal in python ? I set a signal handler, when the signal occur ,how does python invoke my function? Does the OS invoke it just like C program?
If I am in a C extend of python ,is it interrupted immediately ?

---

Now it's clear to me how does python process handle a signal . When you set a signal by the signal module , the module will register a function signal_handler(see $src/Modules/signalmodule.c) ,which set your handler and flag it as 1(`Handlers[sig_num].tripped = 1;`) , then call Py_AddPendingCall to tell python interpreter. The python interpreter will invoke Py_MakePendingCalls to call PyErr_CheckSignals which calls your function in main loop(see $src/Python/ceval.c).
communicate me if you want to talk about this : renenglish@gmail.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set a Python code signal handler using the signal module the interpreter will only run it when it re-enters the byte-code interpreter. The handler is not run right away. It is placed in a queue when the signal occurs. If the code path is currently in C code, built-in or extension module, the handler is deferred until the C code returns control to the Python byte code interpreter. This can be a long time, and you can't really predict how long.

Most notably if you are using interactive mode with readline enabled your signal handler won't run until you give it some input to interpret. this is because the input code is in the readline library (C code) and doesn't return to the interpreter until it has a complete line.

Comment: So the python interpreter handles the signal and calls my function .I want to know how this happen . I read ignalmodule.c , python funcs are appended to an array , and PyErr_CheckSignals invoke the function those are fired . However, where is PyErr_CheckSginals invoked when a signal is sent by OS ?

Comment: It is not invoked when a signal is sent by the OS. It is explicitly called in various places in the interpreter when signal handlers may be run, such as when printing, reading user input, etc. It runs the interrupt handler queue.

Comment: Thx very much ! Now it's clear to me how does python process handle a signal . When you set a signal by the signal module , the module will register a function signal_handler(see $src/Modules/signalmodule.c) ,which set your handler and flag it as 1(Handlers[sig_num].tripped = 1;) , then call Py_AddPendingCall to tell python interpreter. The python interpreter will invoke Py_MakePendingCalls to call PyErr_CheckSignals which calls your function in mail loop(see $src/Python/ceval.c).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [signal module](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html). If you invoke a signal to a python script, from my understanding if there is a handler for it will first process that signal, and potentially has the ability to handle and ignore certain signals. ie. instead of killing on a SIGKILL, you attempt to perform some shutdown cleanup work before killing.