# Execution of Python signal handlers

Tags: python-3.x, signals

I am new to python. I want to understand how python execute signal .I started reading the official documentation. The following statements doesn't  make sense

1.Python signal handler does not get executed inside the low-level (C) signal handler. Instead, the low-level signal handler sets a flag which tells the virtual machine to execute the corresponding Python signal handler at a later point(for example at the next bytecode instruction).

2."Python signal handlers are always executed in the main Python thread of the main interpreter, even if the signal was received in another thread."
Can someone help me

Answer (score 1):

When you are registering signal handlers, you primarily are opting for asynchronous handling of the signals. When the signal is received, the code execution jumps to those registered signal handlers (There are exceptions check [`sigaction`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)). You can't do much in the signal handlers, and it is safe only to call [`async-signal-safe`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) functions.

Python doesn't immediately jump to the signal handler (registered by the user) when the signal is received, and it instead jumps to the low-level C signal handler where it just queues what to execute later (Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6420224/8485028))

As each process has its own signal queue, each thread in the process has its own signal queue. But the thread signal queue is the union of its own queue and the process queue; that is how POSIX threads are modeled. And this feature is exploited for inter-thread communication (achieved using [pthread_sigmask](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html) and [sigwait](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigwait.3.html)). But that is not the case with python. Python signal handlers are always executed in the main interpreter's main python thread, and only the main thread of the main interpreter is allowed to set a new signal handler.